# Fast execution of function which resembles matrix multiplication

Tags: python, performance, matrix, cython, numba

I am trying to make the following function as fast as possible on large matrices. The matrices can have dimensions in the range of 10K-100K. The matrix values are always between 0 and 1. The function resembles matrix multiplication, but with log operations in the inner loop. These log operations appear to be a bottleneck.

I tried various ways of using Numba and Cython. I also tried writing as much as I could with Numpy. I also experimented with doing fewer memory lookups, but this did not seem to give much advantage. The fastest version is below. High precision is greatly preferred, but if there is a way to increase speed at its expense, that would also be appreciated. Thank you for your feedback.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import njit, prange

@numba.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def f(A, B):

    len_A = A.shape[0]
    len_B = B.shape[0]
    num_factors = B.shape[1]        
    C = np.zeros((len_A, len_B))

    for i in prange(len_A):
        for j in prange(len_B):         
            for a in prange(num_factors):

                A_elem = A[i,a]
                B_elem = B[j,a]
                AB_elem = (A_elem + B_elem)/2

                C[i,j] += A_elem * np.log(A_elem/AB_elem) + \
                          B_elem * np.log(B_elem/AB_elem) + \
                          (1-A_elem) * np.log((1-A_elem)/(1-AB_elem)) + \
                          (1-B_elem) * np.log((1-B_elem)/(1-AB_elem))

    C = (np.maximum(C, 0)/2*num_factors)**0.5
    return C

#A = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)
#B = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)
#f(A, B)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can rearrange your equation from

\$
AB_{ija} = \frac{1}{2}(A_{ia} + B_{ja})
\$

\$
\begin{align}
C_{ij} = \sum_a & A_{ia}\cdot \log\left(\frac{A_{ia}}{AB_{ija}}\right) + B_{ja}\cdot \log\left(\frac{B_{ja}}{AB_{ija}}\right) + \\
&+ (1-A_{ia})\cdot \log\left(\frac{1-A_{ia}}{1-AB_{ija}}\right) + (1-B_{ja})\cdot \log\left(\frac{1-B_{ja}}{1-AB_{ija}}\right)
\end{align}
\$

to

\$
\begin{align}
C_{ij} = \sum_a & A_{ia} \cdot \log A_{ia} + B_{ja}\cdot \log B_{ja} - 2AB_{ija}\cdot \log AB_{ija}\\
&+ (1-A_{ia}) \cdot \log (1-A_{ia}) + (1-B_{ja})\cdot \log (1-B_{ja}) - 2(1-AB_{ija})\cdot \log (1-AB_{ija})\\
= \sum_a & A_{ia}\cdot \log A_{ia} + \sum_a B_{ja}\cdot \log B_{ja} - 2\sum_a AB_{ija}\cdot \log AB_{ija} + \dots
\end{align}
\$

This will at least save you some divisions, which can be a bit slower. But the crucial part is to see that you can compute the sums separately. The sums with only \$A\$ or \$B\$ are a lot less computation, which you would otherwise repeat, and only the combined terms are (computationally) hard.

It also means that there is probably a  `numpy` way to eliminate at least some of your `for` loops, which might give you a bit of a speedup, although `numba` will negate some of that (by already having sped up the `for` loops). The hard part is then to use the `numpy` broadcasting correctly to achieve this, which is left as an exercise for now :).

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this by rearranging the function as follows (writing `z=(a+b)/2`):

```
a log(a/z) + b log(b/z) + (1-a) log( (1-a)/(1-z) ) + (1-b) log( (1-b)/(1-z) )

= a log(a) + b log(b) + (1-a) log(1-a) + (1-b) log(1-b) - 2z log(z) - 2(1-z)log(1-z)
```

The first 4 terms can be evaluated outside the main loop, so that you only need to evaluate `log(z)` and `log(1-z)` within the inner loop. This should give close to a factor 2 speed up.

Since the remaining function to evaluate in the inner loop, `z log(z) + (1-z)log(1-z)` is a function of a single variable, you could possible replace this with a look-up table .... but I don't know how much you would gain from that.

Alternatively, use

```
-log(0.5) - 2*(z-0.5)**2 > -z log(z) - (1-z)log(1-z) > -2z * log(0.5)
```

to first get upper and lower bounds for each `C[i,j]` and then focus attention on those values for which the upper bound is greater than the maximum of the lower bounds.